# Splitting a string based on another variable

Tags: python

I get the desired output with the following code:

```
row='s3://bucket-name/qwe/2022/02/24/qwe.csv'
new_row = row.split('s3://bucket-name/')[1]

print(new_row)
qwe/2022/02/24/qwe.csv
```

I want to achieve this while having the bucket name saved in a variable, like this:

```
bucket_name="bucket-name"
new_row = row.split('s3://'+bucket_name+'/')[1]
```

This doesn't work (says invalid syntax).

Is there another way I can define this or will I have to use a different function to split?

Comment: you appear to be assigning `bucket_name` to another variable called `bucket-name` which probably doesn't exist.  I'm guessing you want `"bucket-name"` instead.  When asking these questions, if you post the traceback of the error you are getting, it will help us help you.

Comment: it works fine for me did you miss to declare `bucket_name` as a `string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops you have missed quotes

```
bucket_name='bucket-name'
new_row = row.split('s3://'+bucket_name+'/')[1]
```

ouytput

```
'qwe/2022/02/24/qwe.csv'
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I do have the bucket_name defined with a string (corrected in the post) but I still get the "invalid syntax" error.

Comment: Are you sure? here I'm attcahing screenshot of my view

Comment: Ah, there was an error somewhere else in my code. Thank you. Accepting answer when it lets me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this:

```
row='s3://bucket-name/qwe/2022/02/24/qwe.csv'
bucket_name='bucket-name'
new_row = row.split(f"""s3://{bucket_name}/""")[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any advantage to `split` when you could just slice the url to get the part you want.

```
>>> row='s3://bucket-name/qwe/2022/02/24/qwe.csv'
>>> bucket_name = "bucket-name"
>>> row[len("s3://" + bucket_name + "/"):]
'qwe/2022/02/24/qwe.csv'
```

But since this is a URL, you will have more robust solution if you parse the url. You can use the parts to verify that you got the string you want and it will deal with other issues such appended query strings.

```
from urllib.parse import urlsplit
row='s3://bucket-name/qwe/2022/02/24/qwe.csv'
parts = urlsplit(row)
if parts.scheme != "s3":
    raise ValueError("not s3 bucket")
if parts.netloc != "bucket-name":
    raise ValueError("not my bucket")
print(parts.path[1:])
```

Comment: This is also an appropriate solution. Thank you